# How to the crop image with custom painter in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the make custom shape image cropper in the Flutter. I'm use custom painter for the this project. But I couldn't make to this. The black square line widget is my custom cropper in the first picture. But in the second picture, the form I want is. How can I crop the image like in the second form ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;
  final List linePoints;
  MyPainter({
    required this.image,
    required this.linePoints,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();

    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.strokeWidth = 2;

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(20, size.height / 6), paint);

    canvas.drawLine(linePoints[0][0], linePoints[0][1], paint);
    canvas.drawLine(linePoints[1][0], linePoints[1][1], paint);
    canvas.drawLine(linePoints[2][0], linePoints[2][1], paint);
    canvas.drawLine(linePoints[3][0], linePoints[3][1], paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E0N4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqNlv.png)

Comment: There is a confusion in the pictures, the picture I want is the 1st picture

Comment: Hey, were you able to do cropping using the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly, the sample code is as follows.

Clipper

```dart
class ImageClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(width * 0.1, height * 0.05);
    path.lineTo(width * 0.3, height * 0.9);
    path.lineTo(width * 0.9, height * 0.6);
    path.lineTo(width * 0.5, height * 0.6);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Main Widget

```dart
final image = "https://picsum.photos/id/234/200/200";
final _globalKey = GlobalKey();

RepaintBoundary(
  key: _globalKey,
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: ImageClipper(),
    child: Image.network(image, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity,),
  ),
),
```

Save Function

```dart
  void saveImage() async {
    // Get the boundary object for the RenderRepaintBoundary
    RenderRepaintBoundary? boundaryObject = _globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
    if (boundaryObject == null) return;

    // Capture the image from the boundary object
    ui.Image image = await boundaryObject.toImage();
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    if (byteData == null) return;

    // Convert the byte data to Uint8List
    Uint8List bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    // Get the application documents directory
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create a file with a desired name and write the image bytes to it
    final file = File('${directory.path}/image.png');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    // Save the image to the gallery using GallerySaver
    final result = await GallerySaver.saveImage(file.path);
    if (result == true) {
      print('Image Saved');
    }
  }
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NQR8.jpg)

full code

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final image = "https://picsum.photos/id/234/200/200";
  final _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(image), fit: BoxFit.cover, opacity: 0.32)
                ),
                child: RepaintBoundary(
                  key: _globalKey,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: ImageClipper(),
                    child: Image.network(image, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity,),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: saveImage, 
                child: const Text("Save Image")
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveImage() async {
    // Get the boundary object for the RenderRepaintBoundary
    RenderRepaintBoundary? boundaryObject = _globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
    if (boundaryObject == null) return;

    // Capture the image from the boundary object
    ui.Image image = await boundaryObject.toImage();
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    if (byteData == null) return;

    // Convert the byte data to Uint8List
    Uint8List bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    // Get the application documents directory
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Create a file with a desired name and write the image bytes to it
    final file = File('${directory.path}/image.png');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    // Save the image to the gallery using GallerySaver
    final result = await GallerySaver.saveImage(file.path);
    if (result == true) {
      print('Image Saved');
    }
  }
}

class ImageClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(width * 0.1, height * 0.05);
    path.lineTo(width * 0.3, height * 0.9);
    path.lineTo(width * 0.9, height * 0.6);
    path.lineTo(width * 0.5, height * 0.6);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: So how can I save the picture like this ?

Comment: oh sorry my fault, i'm rearranging the code, you can save the image this way.